# Norm of a monic invertible polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, normed-spaces

Let $\bar D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|\leq 1\}$. Let $p:\bar D\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an monic polynomial which has no roots $\bar D$. Can we say that the uniform norm of $p$ denoted by $\|p\|_\infty$ is greater than or equal to 2? Note $\|p\|_\infty=sup\{ p(z):z\in \bar D\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $p$ is holomorphic, we have by the maximum modulus principle that $\|p\|_{\infty} = \sup_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \lvert p(z)\rvert$. Then, by Theorem 16.1.5 in [*Analytic Theory of Polynomials*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FzFEEVO3PXYC&lpg=PA636&pg=PA643#v=onepage&q&f=false), by Rahman and Schmeisser, for coefficients $c_j$ and $c_k$ of $z^j$ and $z^k$ in $p$ (which is a degree $n$ polynomial) with $j\leq k < n$ and $k\leq n-1-j$, if $\|p\|_{\infty}\leq 2$, then $$\lvert c_n\rvert+\frac{1}{2}(\lvert c_j\rvert+\lvert c_k\rvert)\leq 2$$ We let $j = k = 0$ to get $\lvert c_n\rvert+\lvert c_0\rvert\leq 2$. We know that $\lvert c_n\rvert = 1$ from the fact that $p$ is monic, and we also know that $c_0$ is the product (times $(-1)^n$) of the roots of $p$ and therefore has a norm greater than $1$. Thus, as $\lvert c_n\rvert+\lvert c_0\rvert > 2$, we must have that $\|p\|_{\infty} > 2$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Michael. Could you please tell how you improvised theorem 16.1.5 for the '1' case (that is if $|f(z)|\leq 1$, then $|a_0|+\frac{1}{2}(|a_j|+|a_k|)\leq 1)$ to the '2' case?

Comment: If  $\|p\|_\infty\leq 2$, then did you apply the theorem  by taking $f=\frac{p}{2}$?

Comment: Exactly. We get that $\|p/2\|_{\infty}\leq 1$ implies $\lvert c_0/2\rvert+\frac{1}{2}(\lvert c_j/2\rvert+\lvert c_k/2\rvert)\leq 1$. Then you just pull out the $1/2$ from each and multiply both sides by $2$.